# How were noble gases discovered?

Tags: history, elements, inert-gases

Noble gases are chemically neutral. They don't react with anything.

So, how were they discovered?

Comment: Inert gas is an engineering term; I think you meant noble gas.

Comment: As stated this sounds more like a chemistry question to me, not a physics question. Although admittedly there were physics techniques involved in the discoveries, and if this were rewritten to focus specifically on those techniques (mainly spectroscopy I guess), it might seem more on-topic.

Comment: Rayleigh and Ramsay received the 1904 Nobel Prizes in Physics and in Chemistry, respectively, for their discovery of the noble gases. You might find this amusing!

Comment: I think there's room on this site for interesting physical chemistry questions.

Comment: And by the way, they where discovered by there physical quality (volume, density), despite their chemical (almost) perfect neutrality.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, this is not true that noble gases do not form any compounds -- it can be done with some chemical tricks, usually using fluorine and some hell conditions.

Yet, you don't need any chemistry to detect a new element -- helium was for instance first spotted in the sunlight spectrum. The isolation can also be made by physical means only; the most efficient idea is to cool down air isolating each new fraction that turns into liquid, but there are dozens of other.

Comment: Thanks! I am surprised to know that they can actually form compounds! wow!

Answer (score 8):

The history is summed up in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas#History . The concept of noble gas emerged from the discovery of argon.

As said by mpq, the first to be seen spectroscopically was Helium. Then Argon was detected as a component of the air less reactive than nitrogen (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon#History ).